# Understanding quotient groups of $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The following questions are from *John B. Fraleigh*'s *A First Course in Abstract Algebra*. I have a hard time visualizing the examples of normal subgroup.

> Let $U$ be the multiplicative group $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : |z|=1\}$.
>
> 1. Let $z_0 \in U$. Show that $z_0U = \{z_0z : z \in U\}$ is a subgroup of $U$, and compute $U/z_0U$.
> 2. To what group is $U/\langle-1\rangle$ isomorphic to?

The first part of question 1 is rather straight-forward. My problem is computing $U/z_0U$. I take any $z \in U$, then $zz_0U = \{zz_0g : |g|=1\}$ but I cannot observe anything special about this quotient group.

For the second question, if I regard the whole $U$ as the unit circle, then every quotient group produced would contain two elements, one on the upper hemisphere while one on the lower. Together the two points form a diameter. But I cannot write down the isomorphic pairs explicitly. I think that I should look for an infinite group, right?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the first one: try to characterize left cosets: for $\;u_1,u_2\in U$

$$u_1z_0U=u_2z_0U\iff u_1^{-1}u_2=z_0u\in z_0U\iff u_2=z_0uu_1\in z_0U$$

and the above says $\;z_U=U\;$ , which is also easy to see directly:

$$\forall\;u\in U\;,\;\;u=z_0\left(z_0^{-1}u\right)\in z_0U$$

and from here $\;U/z_0U\cong \{1\}=\;\text{the trivial group}\;$

For the second do something similar. Putting $\;I:=\langle -1\rangle\;$ for simplicity, we observe that $\;I=\{-1,1\}\;$ , so $\;I\cong C_2:=$ the cyclic group with two elements. I now leave this for you.

Comment: Thank you for replying. In fact, whenever I have a quotient group, is characterizing left cosets a common approach to investigate it? For the second one, I have I≅Z2. Then for all z∈U,zI={z,−z}? Then what happen lol